# React Dnd with material ui card

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-dnd

I am having two columns on my React web app. I want to have have a list of draggable material ui cards(in first column) which I want to drag cards from one column to another. Material UI doesn't provide an inbuilt drag functionality with cards right now. Is it possible to do it with react dnd?? If yes then how?

Comment: I'll spare you the usual questions like "what have you tried?" and "are you getting an error? what kind?"... See this: http://rafaelquintanilha.com/sortable-targets-with-react-dnd/ and just replace divs with Cards

Answer (score 1):

I guess when you use Card from material-ui, you may want to create `CardDND` component which has following pattern

```
 import Card from 'material-ui/Card
 import { DragSource } from 'react-dnd'
 const CardDND = (props) => {
  const { connectToDragSource } = props;
  return connectToDragSource(<Card {...props} />);
 }
 export default DragSource('CARD', spec, collect)(CardDND)
```

Comment: what us the spec and collect here